# How to close a System.Diagnostics.Process with no variable referring to the process

Tags: c#

This example code is an over simplification but demonstrates the nature of the problem.

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
 proc.Start();
 proc == null;
```

Is there any way to regain a reference to the process or can I only Close it from the task manager?

Comment: What you know about that process?

Comment: There are constructors which can find a process for you from those running.

Comment: Hamlet Hakobyan, I am using it to launch a jar on a remote machine. I don't have permissions to view the processes on the server and kill it.

Comment: If you know the name of the process then you can [GetProcessByName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/z3w4xdc9), but I wouldn't consider it to be very robust; what if there are more than one process with the same name? A better solution would be to not lose the reference to the process in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call [Process.GetProcesses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/1f3ys1f9) to get a list of all the processes. Then search that list for the one you want. Or, if you know the exact name of the process, you can call [GetProcessesByName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessesbyname).

Once you find the process you want, you can call [Kill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.process.kill).

If, as you mentioned in your comment, you don't have permissions to view the processes, then you're pretty much out of luck. You'd better keep the `Process` reference when you create it. If you didn't create the process, then even if you *did* have permissions to find it, you probably wouldn't have permissions to kill it.